# Rect value not updating x postition?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pygame

I'm creating a game with cars coming at you. I want the cars to change x_pos every time they go off the screen, but for some reason the value changes but the cars don't actually move. I don't know how to fix this and was wondering if there's something I have to do to make it change. If you want to test my code just remove the background and everything else will work. Thanks.

```
import time, pygame, random
import math
pygame.init()
#First Variables
BLACK = (0, 0, 0)
BLUE = (0, 0, 255)
GREEN = (100, 255, 100)
ORANGE = (255, 140, 0)
YELLOW = (155, 135, 12)
white = (255, 255, 255)
GOLD = (255, 215, 0)
screenwidth = 500
screenheight = 500
Lines = True
Space = True
color = random.sample(range(250), 3)
i = []
x = 247
y = - 20
y1 = 40
y2 = 100
y3 = 160
y4 = 220
y5 = 280
y6 = 340
y7 = 400
y8 = 460
#Display and caption
win = pygame.display.set_mode((screenwidth, screenheight))
pygame.display.set_caption('Lil cary')
clock = pygame.time.Clock()
#Load in images
bkg = pygame.image.load('BG.jpg')

#Actual player class
class player():
    def __init__(self):
        self.color = (12, 124, 134)
        self.vel = 5
        self.grassdamage = 0
        self.image = pygame.Surface([50, 100], pygame.SRCALPHA, 32)
        pygame.draw.rect(self.image, (self.color), (0, 0, 50, 100))
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect(center = (200, 390))
        self.damage1 = False
        self.damage2 = False
        self.damage3 = False
        self.damage4 = False
        self.damage5 = False
        self.damage6 = False
        self.damage7 = False
        self.damage8 = False
        self.dead = False
        self.score = 0
    def draw (self, win):
        #pygame.draw.rect(win, (self.color), (self.x, self.y, self.width, self.height))
        win.blit(self.image, self.rect.topleft)
    def moveback(self):
        if self.rect.y < 390 and self.rect.y >= 0:
            self.rect.y += 10
    def grass(self):
        if self.rect.x > -10 and self.rect.x < 150:
            self.grassdamage += 1
            self.vel = 3
        elif self.rect.x > 300 and self.rect.x < 500:
            self.vel =3
            self.grassdamage += 1
        else:
            self.vel = 5
    def grasshealth(self):
        if self.grassdamage == 100:
            self.damage1 = True
        elif self.grassdamage == 200:
            self.damage2 = True
        elif self.grassdamage == 300:
            self.damage3 = True
        elif self.grassdamage == 400:
            self.damage4 = True
        elif self.grassdamage == 500:
            self.damage5 = True
        elif self.grassdamage == 600:
            self.damage6 = True
        elif self.grassdamage == 600:
            self.damage6 = True
        elif self.grassdamage == 700:
            self.damage7 = True
        elif self.grassdamage == 800:
            self.damage8 = True
            self.dead = True
    def death(self):
        if self.dead == True:
            raise SystemExit ('YOU MOFO DIED')
    def scorecount (self):
        if self.score >= 15:
            raise SystemExit ('YOU WIN OMG KIDS')
    def scoredraw(self):
        Text = pygame.font.Font('freesansbold.ttf', 25)
        TextSurf, TextRect1 = text_objects("Score: " + str(self.score), Text)
        TextRect1.center = ((50), (450))
        win.blit(TextSurf, TextRect1)

#Text Setup
def text_objects(text, font):
    textSurface = font.render(text, True, BLACK)
    return textSurface, textSurface.get_rect()
#Drawing damage bar
def drawbar ():
    if player.damage1 == True and car.damage1 == False or car.damage1 == True:
        pygame.draw.rect(win, (GOLD), (50, 50, 25, 25))
    if player.damage2 == True and car.damage1 == False or car.damage1 == True:
        pygame.draw.rect(win, (GOLD), (50, 75, 25, 25))
    if car.damage1 == True and player.grassdamage <= 200:
        player.grassdamage = 201
    if player.damage3 == True and car.damage2 == False or car.damage2 == True:
        pygame.draw.rect(win, (GOLD), (50, 100, 25, 25))
    if player.damage4 == True and car.damage2 == False or car.damage2 == True:
        pygame.draw.rect(win, (GOLD), (50, 125, 25, 25))
    if car.damage2 == True and player.grassdamage <= 400:
        player.grassdamage = 401
    if player.damage5 == True and car.damage3 == False or car.damage3 == True:
        pygame.draw.rect(win, (GOLD), (50, 150, 25, 25))
    if player.damage6 == True and car.damage3 == False or car.damage3 == True:
        pygame.draw.rect(win, (GOLD), (50, 175, 25, 25))
    if car.damage3 == True and player.grassdamage <= 600:
        player.grassdamage = 601
    if player.damage7 == True and car.damage4 == False or car.damage4 == True:
        pygame.draw.rect(win, (GOLD), (50, 200, 25, 25))
    if player.damage8 == True and car.damage4 == False or car.damage4 == True:
        pygame.draw.rect(win, (GOLD), (50, 225, 25, 25))
        raise SystemExit ('YOU LOST')
    if car.damage4 == True and player.grassdamage <= 800:
        player.grassdamage = 800
    pygame.draw.rect(win, (0,0,0), (50, 50, 25, 200), 3)
    Text = pygame.font.Font('freesansbold.ttf', 20)
    TextSurf, TextRect = text_objects("Damage", Text)
    TextRect.center = ((65), (30))
    win.blit(TextSurf, TextRect)


class car1():
    ROAD_LEFT = 175
    ROAD_RIGHT = 300
    def __init__(self):
        self.x_pos = random.randrange(car1.ROAD_LEFT, car1.ROAD_RIGHT)
        self.color = random.sample(range(250), 3)
        self.image = pygame.Surface([50, 100], pygame.SRCALPHA, 32)
        pygame.draw.rect(self.image, (self.color), (0, 0, 50, 100))
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect(topleft = (self.x_pos, -100))
        self.carvel = random.randrange(8, 10)
        self.damage = 0
        self.damage1 = False
        self.damage2 = False
        self.damage3 = False
        self.damage4 = False
    def draw(self, win):
        #pygame.draw.rect(win,(self.color),self.rect)
        win.blit(self.image, self.rect.topleft)
    def move(self):
        if self.rect.y < 530:
            self.rect.y += self.carvel
        else:
            self.rect.y = -100
            player.score += 1
            self.color = random.sample(range(250), 3)
            self.carvel = random.randrange(6, 8)
            self.x_pos = random.randrange(car1.ROAD_LEFT, car1.ROAD_RIGHT)
    def collision_check(self, another_object):
        if self.rect.colliderect(another_object):
            print('collison')
            self.rect.y = -100
            self.damage += 1
    def cardamage(self):
        if self.damage == 1:
            self.damage1 = True
            player.damage1 = True
            player.damage2 = True
        if self.damage == 2:
            self.damage2 = True
            player.damage3 = True
            player.damage4 = True
        if self.damage == 3:
            self.damage3 = True
            player.damage5 = True
            player.damage6 = True
        if self.damage == 4:
            self.damage4 = True
            player.damage7 = True
            player.damage8 = True


        #Putting variables to the classes
player = player()
car = car1()
car_list = [ car ]  # start with one car
car_add_time = 0
#Main drawing function
def redrawgamewindow():
    win.blit(bkg, (0, 0))
    pygame.draw.rect(win, (0, 0, 0), (150, 0, 200, 500))
    pygame.draw.rect(win, (255, 255, 255), (x, (y), 10, 30))
    pygame.draw.rect(win, (255, 255, 255), (x, (y1), 10, 30))
    pygame.draw.rect(win, (255, 255, 255), (x, (y2), 10, 30))
    pygame.draw.rect(win, (255, 255, 255), (x, (y3), 10, 30))
    pygame.draw.rect(win, (255, 255, 255), (x, (y4), 10, 30))
    pygame.draw.rect(win, (255, 255, 255), (x, (y5), 10, 30))
    pygame.draw.rect(win, (255, 255, 255), (x, (y6), 10, 30))
    pygame.draw.rect(win, (255, 255, 255), (x, (y7), 10, 30))
    pygame.draw.rect(win, (255, 255, 255), (x, (y8), 10, 30))
    player.draw(win)
    for car in car_list:
        car.draw(win)
    player.grasshealth()
    for car in car_list:
        car.cardamage()
    player.grass()
    player.death()
    for car in car_list:
        car.collision_check(player.rect)
        car.move()
    drawbar()
    player.scorecount()
    player.scoredraw()
    pygame.display.update()
#MAINLOOP

run = True
while run:
    #Making background and FPS
    clock.tick(80)
    #Quiting Funciton
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            run = False
        elif event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
            if event.key == pygame.K_ESCAPE:
                run = False
    time_now = pygame.time.get_ticks()

    if (time_now - car_add_time > 5000):
        new_car = car1()
        car_list.append(new_car)
        car_add_time = time_now
    #Scrolling the lines
    if Lines:
        y += player.vel
        y1 += player.vel
        y2 += player.vel
        y3 += player.vel
        y4 += player.vel
        y5 += player.vel
        y6 += player.vel
        y7 += player.vel
        y8 += player.vel
    if Lines:
        if y >= 500:
            y = -40
        if y1 >= 500:
            y1 = -40
        if y2 >= 500:
            y2 = -40
        if y3 >= 500:
            y3 = -40
        if y4 >= 500:
            y4 = -40
        if y5 >= 500:
            y5 = -40
        if y6 >= 500:
            y6 = -40
        if y7 >= 500:
            y7 = -40
        if y8 >= 500:
            y8 = -40
    #User input
    keys = pygame.key.get_pressed()
    #Boost controller
    if keys[pygame.K_SPACE]:
        start_time = time.time()
        if player.rect.y > 200:
            player.rect.y -= 9
            Space = True
    else:
        player.moveback()
        end_time = time.time()
    #Left movement
    if  keys[pygame.K_LEFT] and player.rect.x > 150:
        player.rect.x -= 5
    if keys [pygame.K_LEFT] and player.rect.x <= 150:
        if player.rect.x > 0:
            player.rect.x -=5
    #Right movement
    if keys[pygame.K_RIGHT] and player.rect.x < 300:
        player.rect.x += 5
    if keys[pygame.K_RIGHT]and player.rect.x >= 300:
        if player.rect.x < 500 - player.rect.width:
            player.rect.x += 5

    #Grass and grass damage

    #MAIN DRAW RECALL
    redrawgamewindow()
```

Comment: Please only show us relevant code, which we can use to test. Instead of the entire program.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not sufficient to set a random value to `self.x_pos`. For drawing the "car" the position of the [`pygame.Rect`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/rect.html) object `self.rect` is used:

> ```py
> def draw(self, win):
>    win.blit(self.image, self.rect.topleft)
> ```

So you've to change `self.rect.x`, too:

```py
class car1():
    # [...]

    def move(self):
        if self.rect.y < 530:
            self.rect.y += self.carvel
        else:
            self.rect.y = -100
            player.score += 1
            self.color = random.sample(range(250), 3)
            self.carvel = random.randrange(6, 8)
            self.x_pos = random.randrange(car1.ROAD_LEFT, car1.ROAD_RIGHT)
            self.rect.x = self.x_pos # <---------------------------------------
```